# Tangent space of moduli of stable vector bundles

Tags: vector-bundles, moduli-spaces, deformation-theory

I'm new to this area, so it may very well be possible that I may be missing something easy here.

Let $E$ be a stable complex vector bundle over $X$ of degree $d$ and rank $n$. Then the moduli space $\mathcal{M}^s(n,d)$ of degree $d$ rank $n$ stable vector bundles can be identified with the space of holomorphic structures on $E$.

Further the tangent space to $\mathcal{M}^s(n,d)$ can be seen to be $H^{0,1}(X, End(E))$, where $End(E)$ denotes the endomorphism bundle. Similarly the tangent space to the space of deformations of a complex structure of $E$ can be seen to be $H^{0,1}(E,T^{1,0}E)$.

Given the identification in the previous paragraph, how does one describe the isomorphism  between $H^{0,1}(X, End(E))$ and $H^{0,1}(E,T^{1,0}E)$ ?

Comment: What is the meaning of $T^{1,0}E $?

Comment: It denotes the holomorphic tangent bundle of E.

Comment: What you are missing is that deformations of $E$ as a manifold will not usually keep the vector bundle structure — in fact, what you denote by $H^{1,0}(E, T^{1,0}E)$ is usually infinite-dimensional.

Comment: @cr1t1cal The moduli space $\mathcal{M}^s(n,d)$ is not identified with the holomorphic structure on $E$. In fact $Hol(E)/\sim_{\text{iso}}$ is not even a coarse moduli space. Isomorphism exists between $\mathcal{M}^s(n,d)$ and the space of irreducible Yang-Mills connections with unitary holonomy up to the action of the Gauge group $\mathcal{G}_E:=GL(E)$

Comment: @abx ah yes, that makes sense. Thanks for clarifying my confusion!